# Hubo - How to get flow / thread users

Tags: hubot, flowdock

How to get the users list from the current flow / thread with Hubot on Flowdock? I'd like to create plugin showing messages with the usage of current flow user names.
I have found this: robot.brain.data.users
but it returns the whole list of users from organization rather than from the current flow.

Answer (score 0):

The list of a flow’s users can be fetched using the Flows resource.  You'll need to know the Organization name and Flow name.  See the 'Get a Flow' section here:

https://www.flowdock.com/api/flows

The format is:

```
GET /flows/:organization/:flow
```

and returns:

```
{
  "id": "deadbeefdeadbeef",
  "name": "My flow",
  "parameterized_name": "my-flow",
  "organization": {
    "id": 8,
    "name": "Acme",
    "parameterized_name": "acme",
    "user_limit": 0,
    "user_count": 5,
    "active": true,
    "url": "https://api.flowdock.com/organizations/acme"
  }
  "unread_mentions": 0,
  "open": true,
  "url": "https://api.flowdock.com/flows/acme/my-flow",
  "web_url": "https://www.flowdock.com/app/acme/my-flow",
  "join_url": "https://www.flowdock.com/invitations/eedd2bf0643f75c14be9099272429351c7132a71-my-flow",
  "access_mode": "link",
  "users": [
    {
      "id": 9,
      "nick": "Joe",
      "name": "Joe Smith",
      "email": "joe@example.com",
      "avatar": "https://d2cxspbh1aoie1.cloudfront.net/avatars/f5b8fb60c6116331da07c65b96a8a1d1/",
      "status": "Testing API",
      "disabled": false,
      "last_activity": 1328016726423000,
      "last_ping": 1328017690004000
    },
    {
      "id": 42,
      "nick": "Stevie",
      "name": "Stevie Johnson",
      "email": "stevie@example.com",
      "avatar": "https://d2cxspbh1aoie1.cloudfront.net/5bdd089a099acc56fc7120f6325a5d5c/",
      "status": null,
      "disabled": false,
      "last_activity": 1328016712345000,
      "last_ping": 1328017612345000
    }
  ]
}
```